# express cors blocked only on root route of some api

Tags: node.js, express, cors

i have custom cors settings, due to provide custom OPTIONS method. below code

```
// region cors
// app.use(cors()); // - fixme > using cors lib will disable http options for all routes. avoid using it.
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS")
    next();
});
// endregion cors
```

and here is some route. that behaves weirdly.

```
const router = express.Router();

router.options(`/`,  authMiddleware, options);
router.get(`/term`, authMiddleware, search);
router.get(`/`, authMiddleware, search);
router.get(`/recent`, authMiddleware, getRecentSearchHistory);

export {router}
```

you can see
`~/term` and `/` is identical. which i made `~/term` additionally to check if it's working.

the problem is, api request to `/` will be blocked !!?
for some reason, `/term` works just fine, but express will block only the `/` root route.
(which actual abs route is `http://localhost:3000/api/search`)

does express has route name reservation specifically to "search" or something?

i don't understand this behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure I understand the question but I'll take a chance at answering anyway..

The router is a new instance of express, it doesn't inherit app's cors setttings, I haven't used express router in a while but I think if you make the router use cors as well it might work, if you want the `/` route to not get caught by the `/*` route I suggest maybe defining it above the app route.

Here is an example of what I mean

```js
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors';

const router = express.Router();
router.use(cors());

router.options(`/`,  authMiddleware, options);
router.get(`/term`, authMiddleware, search);
router.get(`/`, authMiddleware, search);
router.get(`/recent`, authMiddleware, getRecentSearchHistory);

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(router);

// app.use('/index/', index);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('app listening'));
```

Comment: no what i meant is when you do that. the root `/` will still be blocked by cors.
i do have a proper cors settings on index.ts (main)

Comment: @uzu try doing app.use((res, req, next) => { ... /* Cors Settings */ } );